# Can't generate a form with form helpers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to generate a form with an html.erb file, that looks something like this:

```
<form class="edit-booking" method="post" action="/users/<%= current_user.id %>/accounts/1/bookings/new" data-remote="true">
    <header><h1>Edit booking</h1></header>
    <input class="booking-name" name="booking[name]" placeholder="Name of the user" type="text" />
    <fieldset class="booking-list">
        <h2>Booking details</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input name="booking[name]" type="text" value="Unit name" disabled/>
                <input name="booking[check_in]" type="date" value="" />
                <input name="booking[check_out]" type="date" value="" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>     
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

an I have this ruby code:

```
<%= form_for [current_user] do |f| %>

    <header>
        <h1>Edit booking</h1>
    </header>

    <%= field_set_tag 'Booking details' do %>
        <%= f.fields_for :bookings do |booking_form| %>
            <%= booking_form.text_field :name,     placeholder: "Name" %>
            <%= booking_form.text_field :check_in,   placeholder: "Check-in" %>
            <%= booking_form.text_field :check_out,    placeholder: "Check-out" %>
        <% end %>       
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Save" %> 
<% end %>
```

But what happens is, it doesn't render anything on the browser even though in the chrome dev tool it shows a form tag.

EDIT:

The html generated is as following:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/1/accounts/1" class="edit_account" id="edit_account_1" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="fzA+hkk3o+itJOI0UDj9F01DuI+A5+zgQ1EVGlwrPww="></div>

    <header>
        <h1>Edit booking</h1>
    </header>

    <fieldset><legend>Booking details</legend>



            <input id="account_bookings_name" name="account[bookings][name]" placeholder="Name" type="text">
            <input id="account_bookings_check_in" name="account[bookings][check_in]" placeholder="Check-in" type="text">
            <input id="account_bookings_check_out" name="account[bookings][check_out]" placeholder="Check-out" type="text">

</fieldset>
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save"> 
</form>
```

My Account model:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :products
  has_many :bookings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bookings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products

end
```

Comment: Does the current_user have any bookings?

Comment: yes, I have a booking model that belongs to the user

Comment: Can you show the Chrome output?

Answer (score 0):

In your model add:

```
#Account model

accepts_nested_attributes_for :bookings
```

Also, should your current_user be an account?

Comment: For some reason your fields_for are rendering those: `account[bookings][check_in]` instead of `account[bookings_attributes][check_in]`. This suggest that something is wrong with your nested attributes declaration. Is current user an account? If so could you show us account model?

Comment: I added the account model to the post

Comment: Can you check whether your model responds to `bookings_attributes=` method?

Comment: Try in console: `Account.new.respond_to? :booking_attributes=`

Comment: Does it have to be Account.new.respond_to? :booking_attributes= or :bookings.attributes= ?